# Issues with mocking methods using Moq

Tags: unit-testing, testing, moq

I have the following class that has two static methods Retrieve and RetrieveWithQuery.
Below the classes listed here, I have included a snippet of the test.
All but the last assert of the test fails with the following message:

Failed  TestMethod2 MoqTest Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:. Actual:<(null)>.

I understand that the problem may be that the query that I setup in the mock
is a different instance from the query used in the RetrieveWithQuery method.
And that is why is would be returning null.

In a perfect world I would simply re-factor the service class, unfortunately I am 
working with legacy code that is already production. The goal is to first complete
tests, then re-factor code and run regression testing before updating production 
environment.

Is there a workaround or different way to test this?

```
public class MyService  
{
    public virtual string RetrieveMethod(string account)
    {
        if (account == "The abc company")
        {
            return "Peter Smith";
        }

            return "John Doe";
    }

    public virtual string RetrieveMethod(MyQuery query)
    {
        return RetrieveMethod(query.QueryString);   
    }

    public static string Retrieve(MyService service, string value)
    {
        return service.RetrieveMethod(value);
    }

    public static string RetrieveWithQuery(MyService service, string value)
    {
        var query = new MyQuery
        {
            QueryString = value
        };

        return service.RetrieveMethod(query);
    }

}

public class MyQuery
{
    public string QueryString;
}



    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        var mockService = new Mock<MyService>();

        const string company = "The abc company";
        const string expectedContact = "Peter Smith";

        var queryAccount = new MyQuery
                        {
                            QueryString = company
                        };

        // Setup base retrieve
        mockService.Setup(myServ => myServ.RetrieveMethod(company)).Returns(expectedContact);

        // Setup base retrieve with query
        mockService.Setup(myServ => myServ.RetrieveMethod(queryAccount)).Returns(expectedContact);

        // test base retrieve with query - PASS
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedContact, mockService.Object.RetrieveMethod(queryAccount));

        // test static method retrieve - PASS
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedContact, MyService.Retrieve(mockService.Object, company));

        // test static method retrieve with query - FAIL
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedContact, MyService.RetrieveWithQuery(mockService.Object, company));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your setup:

```
    // Setup base retrieve with query
    mockService.Setup(myServ => myServ.RetrieveMethod(It.Is<Query>(q=>q.QueryString == queryAccount.QueryString)).Returns(expectedContact);
```

Or you could overload on Equals for Query so that the Query that gets created is equal to expectedQuery.

The [Moq QuickStart](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart.) page has good examples of this and more which should help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have another question regarding the answer you provided. How would I go about this if there is another object level to mock? I have tried the following code and it fails.
In this case there is a request and query that needs to be mocked:

  mockService.Setup(myServ => myServ.RetrieveRequestMethod(
                It.Is<MyRequest>(r => r.Query == 
                It.Is<MyQuery>(q => q.QueryString == company)))).Returns(expectedContact);

Comment: That particular line would become `mockService.Setup(myServ => myServ.RetrieveRequestMethod( It.Is<MyRequest>(r => r.Query.QueryString == company)))).Returns(expectedContact);`.  You should think of the body of matching constraints as being the same thing you would write in a hand-rolled mock.  Also, look at the quickstart page and other docs for Moq, they are pretty good: http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart.